# Node module.exports doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making node program. I want to access app.js parameter from child. I used module.exports in parent and module.parent.exports in child. But it didn't work. How can I fix it?

(/app.js)

```
var app = module.exports = express();
```

(/routes/index.js)

```
var app = module.exports = module.parent.exports;
var port = app.get('port');
```

(error message)

```
/Users/satoshi/Google Drive/node/testoy2/routes/index.js:7
 var port = app.get('port');
                ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/satoshi/Google Drive/node/testoy2/routes/index.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/satoshi/Google Drive/node/testoy2/app.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

(version)

```
node = v0.10.5
express = 3.2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
var app = require("../app.js");
```

in your `index.js`.

Comment: You have to use require also to link correctly express module in app.js. Have you done it?

Comment: I used require in app.js. like this,                                       express = require('express')
  , socketIO = require('socket.io')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `app` to the routes during require:
(app.js)

```
...
var app = module.exports = express();
var routes = require('./routes')(app);
```

Then make sure to store it in routes:
(routes/index.js)

```
var expApp = undefined;//This variable will hold the express app
var routes = module.exports = function(app){
   expApp = app;//Now you have access to express
}
```

Any other exports from routes must be explicit export.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I got same error. I also tried to use share module. /lib/share.js Inside share.js is(module.exports = {};) (app.js)require('./lib/share').config = 3000; (index.js)require('./../lib/share').config). But it also didn't work. I got "Error: Cannot find module '../lib/share_valuable'".

Comment: @satoshi - what exactly didn't work? I'm using this technique on my apps and it works fine.